# Programatically access Google Chrome DevTools in GitLab CI

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to access google Chrome Dev tools from within the Gitlab CI in the pipeline to measure the performance tests.Can you please suggest me how to access the Chrome Dev tools , any API or command line so that I can get the performance of the web application and add that step in the build pipeline

GitLab CI able to access the Chrome Dev tools to measure the application performance.